# How to use an expression in a findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'string')]"))

Tags: java, selenium

```
findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'string')]"));
```

Expect result:

```
findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),**String**)]"));
```

which string is an expression

Comment: Do you mean regex expression??

Comment: Can I use a parameter value here if it does not support the regex expression

Comment: Yes, you can use parameter value here as `String param = "something";findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text()," + param +")]"))`

Comment: Yes, I have tried you said, but the actual result is not my expect result. String s = test; WebElement menuButton = r.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),"+s+")]")). the actual result is //span[text(), test] which is unable to locate the element, the expected result is //span[text(), 'text'], can you do more support? Thanks

Comment: Ah, actually I've missed single inverted commas, try with my provided answer that is correct and let me know

Comment: After adding single inverted commas, it works. r.browser.findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'"+s+"‌​')]"))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually `Selenium-WebDriver` uses the [Wicked Good XPath](https://github.com/google/wicked-good-xpath) library that only supports  [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/).

So, regex expression is illegal here and you can use only features and functions of [XPath 1.0](http://www.w3.org/TR/xpath/) using `Selenium-WebDriver`.

> Can I use a parameter value here if it does not support the regex expression

Yes, you can use parameter value **but this parameter value would only treat as string instead of regex expression** as below :-

```
String param = "something";

findElement(By.xpath("//span[contains(text(),'" + param +"')]"))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot @Saurabh Gaur

Answer (score 0):

By default, Selenium uses the "native" version of `xpath` that comes with the browser and xpath 1 doesn't support regex expressions.

Comment: Can I use a parameter value here? If yes, how?